# Sublime SFTP on MacOS - How can I save the file to a different location?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

I've started using the SFTP package for Sublime 3 on MacOS. It's generally pretty good, but it's missing a critical part - I can't find how to save a file to a different location on the same server or another server. Basically the same as "Save As" for local files.

Does anyone know how to do this?

If it can't be done with this package, is there another package that would support this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy. In save as, at the top bar that shows the directory. Click and clear it out. Then type the IP address or network location and hit enter or tab to go to that remote directory. Then when in the desired directory, name the file and save it.

Comment: There is no "Save As" for the SFTP package in Sublime 3 on MacOS.